# unwanted space being added to email field views drupal 7

Tags: view, emailfield

I am in the process of changing a php site over to a drupal.  I am having an issue with rewriting an email field.  I want all the buttons to say "EMAIL", but then I want the buttons to link to the individuals actual email address.  So here's what I've done in views:

- I set the email field up as a text field (when I tried setting it up
  as an email field it added unnecessary characters %40)
- then I rewrote the results
- added text field "EMAIL"
- outputted the field as a link using replacement patterns
  "mailto:[field_email] clicked apply and save

Now when I hover over the email button it shows the correct email only it is adding unwanted space between mailto: and info@info.com (mailto:        between info@info.com).

I need to remove the unnecessary white space between the mailto: and info

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the extra spaces being added between the "mailto:" and "info@info.com" in views you need to disable "Use Field Templates" under the Style Section (while editing the individual field).